# Verbose alternatives to Option with in-band errors and warnings

Tags: scala

In functional programming, you avoid throwing exceptions, which means function return values are the logical location to put your error messages (i.e. in telecom jargon, error messages are in-band.)  This is particularly useful for distributed programming (e.g. actors), but I've found that it is useful in other cases.

In particular, I'm writing a class to send email via a template, and I don't want to bother logging minor issues (e.g. the recipient's name is missing) if it turns out there are bigger issues (e.g. missing email address, or some high-level business rule that's inconvenient to check first.)

Another way to put this is I want to decouple error/warning handling from the execution stack.  I don't want to be forced to check for the most severe errors first, nor do I want to assume they're being checked in the same thread.

I started out with something like this, which is implemented differently for each mail template.  The MessageInfo is the data used to fill the template, and it is a different subclass for each template.

```
trait MessageInfoSource {
    def messageInfo(recipient : Person) : Option(MessageInfo)
}
```

When I implement this, I can be more explicit about the type of MessageInfo I want.  However, if there's a problem, I get a None, rather than a reason.  (If I did it the Java way, I'd throw an unchecked exception; probably a NullPointerException, possibly decorated with all the debug info I could ever want.)

So I wrote this:

```
sealed trait MessageInfoOption extends Iterable[MessageInfo]

case class SomeMessageInfo(messageInfo : MessageInfo) extends MessageInfoOption {
    override def iterator = Some(messageInfo).iterator
}

case class NoMessageInfo(reason : String, debugInfo : Map[String, _ <: AnyRef] = Map.empty) extends MessageInfoOption {
      override def iterator = None.iterator
}
```

If I decide to get fancy, I may add a container for warnings to SomeMessageInfo.

This has the disadvantage that it's tied to a particular class (MessageInfo), and when I try to change it to a more generic type (e.g. [M <: MessageInfo]) I end up in Scala's labyrinth of generics and covariants.

Looking at the source code for Option didn't help-- I want something simple, since I intend to use this pattern *all over the place.*

My solution for now is to go with the latter, and type cast when I unpack. But I'm not happy with that.

Is there some pre-existing library or simple design pattern in Scala that can be dropped in as a replacement for Option that provides more verbose error handling?

Comment: Investigate the Either construct -- where Option[A] is either Some(a: A) or None, Either[A, B] is either Left(a: A) or Right(b: B). It's commonly used to return either a success (by convention, Right) or a failure (by convention, Left).

Also, investigate Scala's Try[A] construct -- it's an elegant/functional way of dealing with exceptions.

Comment: I recommend Try (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Try)

Comment: Great ideas!  Too bad you guys wrote them as comments instead of answers.  I've been using Scala for years, but for some reason never run into Either (except in the source code of Option.)  Try looks really good-- except that I'm still on 1.9. :-(

Comment: I hope that "1.9" is a typo! If it is, you can use 2.9.3, to which `Try` was backported.

Comment: Oops. I am on Scala 2.9, which is 1.3 more than my Java version :-)